# How to do a Pinterest-like UI layout in Meteor? (Edited, anyone use Cast.js?)

Tags: meteor

Very new to webdev here, but trying my hand at Meteor!  I'd like to create a collection that contains some text, a link, and an image and show each item in the collection in a grid-type layout similar to Pinterest.

I have found some resources, such as Meteor-isotope (https://github.com/digioak/meteor-isotope), cast.js (http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/45711238911/create-beautiful-grid-layouts-with-cast-js) and even maybe using twitter bootstrap's own grid system?

Is there a recommended approach to a gridview with Meteor?  Thank you.

Comment: I've used mansonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/) once to make a Pinterest-like UI but not with Meteor and I believe it's compatible with Meteor. Have you ever tried it ?

Answer (score 5):

[Masonry](https://atmospherejs.com/sjors/meteor-masonry) works nicely for me ([here's my app](http://inspireme.meteor.com/result)). Simply add it to your project.

```
meteor add sjors:meteor-masonry
```

In order to make rendering work correctlly with images, you'll also need to add the [imagesLoaded](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/jquery-imagesloaded) library.

```
meteor add mrt:jquery-imagesloaded
```

Here's an example on how to use it in your code:

**result.html**

```
<template name="resultPage">
  <div id="result-container">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{> post}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="post">
  <div class="result-item">
    <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">
      <img src="{{url}}">
    </a>
    <div class="author">
      Submitted by: <strong>{{author}}</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**result.js**

```
Template.resultPage.rendered = function() {
  var $container = $('#result-container');

  $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector : '.result-item'
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this sample project and ended up learning from it.  I'm not sure if it helps others, but this is the project: http://isotest.meteor.com/

Answer (score 0):

I went with isotope myself, but not the meteor package. I ended up having to use the library itself and then use jquery ImagesLoaded to do a isotope reLayout call. The way meteors Template..rendered works doesn't take into effect images or something so my "blocks" would intermittently overlap from time to time. I stopped developing the site but you can see how I went about it at [www.mmohype.com](http://www.mmohype.com). Click any game.